# C++ library for Asynchronous HTTP Client

Tags: c++, http, asynchronous

I am looking for a C++ library to send an asynchronous HTTP request such that main thread is not blocked and notified later once http url request is done.

Please advise if there as such any C++ library to achieve this asynchronous HTTP client feature.

Comment: try boost::asio, but as I remember there is no http realisation, only asynchronous tcp/udp

Comment: I need to have HTTP particularly.

Comment: Please advise me a library having async HTTP client feature.

Comment: try libcurl or libcurlpp

Comment: these libraries have "async" feature, i don't think so ? Please confirm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685109/downloading-http-urls-asynchronously-in-c
As in this question

Comment: Have you looked at the Casablanca library? I think this will do what you want but may not be that portable (from Windows)

Answer (score 3):

libcurl's "multi" interface can run HTTP requests in the background (it uses a 2nd thread, but the effect is the same). First, create a multi handle with `curl_multi_init`. Then, set up an easy handle (create it with `curl_easy_init` and set the URL and other options with `curl_easy_setopt`) and call `curl_multi_add_handle`. `curl_multi_perform` will start the transfer(s) and return immediately, and you can call `curl_multi_info_read` to get the status of your easy handles. Don't forget to call `curl_multi_cleanup` when you're done.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html

Answer (score -2):

The library doesn't have to be asynchronous. As long as it is thread safe, you should be able to do whatever you need to do in a separate thread and use thread primitives to sync up later with the main thread..

Comment: This may be true in some cases, but as an approach it won't scale.